# Laravel - getting the count from two pivot tables as one number

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table with `articles` and two pivot tables `views` and `votes` for articles that have columns `article_id` and `user_id`. For articles I have a column `publish` where I check if the article is published. I need to make a query by popularity, where I get all the published articles with their count from both pivot tables, where each vote from the table `votes` `counts` as `3`, and each count from the table `views` `counts` as `1`. Not sure how to do this, I previously had a query where I was getting published articles with their count of only votes, but I was only getting the articles that had some votes, and not the ones that were published but had no votes. And in the new query I need to add views as well, and change the logic for counting as well as including the articles that are published and not views and order them by their count from these two pivot tables.

So, the wanted output would something like this:

```
[{"id":117,"popularityCount":17},{"id":118,"popularityCount":15},{"id":121,"popularityCount":13}]
```

This was the query, but that is not what I need anymore:

```
$articles = DB::table('articles')
        ->select([DB::raw('articles.id'), DB::raw('COUNT(*) as "votes"')])
        ->join('votes', 'article_id', '=', 'articles.id')
        ->where('articles.publish', 1)
        ->groupBy('votes.article_id')
        ->orderBy('votes', 'desc')
        ->get();

        return $articles;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me in the end if anyone will need it in the future!

```
$result = Article::select('articles.*', 'v.vote_count', 'vw.view_count')
            ->where('publish', 1)
            ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT votes.article_id, COUNT(*) AS vote_count FROM votes GROUP BY votes.article_id) v'), 'v.article_id', '=', 'articles.id')
            ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT views.article_id, COUNT(*) AS view_count FROM views GROUP BY views.article_id) vw'), 'vw.article_id', '=', 'articles.id')
            ->orderByRaw('(v.vote_count * 3) + vw.view_count DESC')
            ->where('created_at', '>', $date->format('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00')
            ->get();
```